Python on Mac does not recognize venv executable
I recently moved to Macbook to do programming. It has a really weird problem that I don't know where to start debugging. I already perform an exhautive search on Google but can't find a solution.
Basically, I try to create a virtual environment env withpython3.10, activate it and expect to have python3.10, but surprisingly, it's python3.12 which different executable.
luanpham@Macc:~/ws/RCAEval$ python3.10 -m venv env
luanpham@Macc:~/ws/RCAEval$ . env/bin/activate
(env) luanpham@Macc:~/ws/RCAEval$ which python
/Users/luanpham/ws/RCAEval/env/bin/python
(env) luanpham@Macc:~/ws/RCAEval$ python --version
Python 3.12.3
(env) luanpham@Macc:~/ws/RCAEval$ python
Python 3.12.3 (v3.12.3:f6650f9ad7, Apr  9 2024, 08:18:47) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ^D
(env) luanpham@Macc:~/ws/RCAEval$ which python3.10
/Users/luanpham/ws/RCAEval/env/bin/python3.10
(env) luanpham@Macc:~/ws/RCAEval$ python
Python 3.12.3 (v3.12.3:f6650f9ad7, Apr  9 2024, 08:18:47) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.executable)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3.12

It would great if anyone can let me know what's happened here...

Damn me, I accidentally have an alias python=python3.12 in my .bashrc

As you mentioned, your python alias aims to python 3.12. If you want a virtual environment for an specific python version:
You can install the latest version of pip using the following. This command will automatically install the latest pip version: python3.10 -m pip install --user --upgrade pip
Now, you can install the venv or virtual environment in Python using the following command.
python3.10 -m pip install --user virtualenv

To create a virtual environment, head to your project directory and run the following command.
python3.10 -m venv venv

Before using your virtual environment on your project, you need to activate it using
source venv/bin/activate

After having it activated you should see your shell should look like: (venv) ~/your/dir. And try to check the python version again
